# Redux Reducer doesn't update the state while payload is true

Tags: redux

Even though my code seems right looking at the documentation the state in my reducer doesn't get updated. I log the values in my reducer and the `type` returns `SIGNIN_USER`, `current state` returns `false` and the `payload` returns `true`.

This is my reducer:

```
import { SIGNIN_USER } from "../constants/action-types";

export default (state = {
    isAuthenticated: false,
}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SIGNIN_USER:
            console.log('Type: ' + action.type);
            console.log('Reducer State: ' + state.isAuthenticated);
            console.log('Reducer Payload: ' + action.payload.authenticated);
            return {
                ...state,
                isAuthenticated: action.payload.authenticated
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

When I hardcode the isAuthenticated state to true it works. But when I set it to false and want to upate it in my Reducer it just doesn't get updated.
I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong.. can someone help me?

Also this is my action:

```
export const signinUser = ({ username, password }) => async dispatch => {
    new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const req = await axios
            /* Make API Post call with user data. */
                .post('api/user/login', {
                    username: username,
                    password: password
                });

            const token = req.data.data.auth_token;
            const success = req.data.success;
            let authenticated = true;


            dispatch({
                type: 'SIGNIN_USER',
                payload: { authenticated }
            });

            if (success){
                localStorage.setItem('jwtToken', token);
                localStorage.setItem('loggedIn', true);
                window.location.assign('/');
            }

            resolve();

        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            reject(e);
        }
    });

};
```

My component where the state needs to be checked:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const privateRouter = ({component: Component, isAuthenticated, ...rest }) => {

    console.log('PrivateRoute privateRouter: ' + isAuthenticated);

    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={props =>
            isAuthenticated ? (
                <Component {...props} />
            ) : (
                <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />
            )}
        />
    )
};

const mapStateToProps = ({ auth }) => ({
    isAuthenticated: auth.isAuthenticated
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(privateRouter);
```

And my Store:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import authReducer from '../reducers/index';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    auth: authReducer
});


const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    compose(
        applyMiddleware(thunk),
        window.REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION
        ? window.REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION()
            :f => f
    )
);

export default store;
```

This is the function where I call my signinUser:

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { username, password } = this.state;
    this.props.signinUser({username, password});
};
```

Comment: in your action, is payload set to true or payload.authenticated? from your description it seems like payload.

Comment: It it set to true. `Console.log(action.payload.authenticated);` returns `true` @callmeroot

Comment: gotcha. where in your app are you seeing it not get updated? in the component? can we see that code?

Comment: I added the store and component where the state needs to be checked. If I hardcode the state in my Reducer it shows true in my component. But if I set it to false and want to update it to true it stays at false. @callmeroot

Comment: where are you calling your signinUser function? can you verify the action is actually getting dispatched?

Comment: did you checked backend response (action.payload.authenticated) is type of Boolean

Comment: @callmeroot the action is dispatched.

Comment: Yes it is a Boolean @DulangaHeshan

Comment: did u check (action.payload.authenticated) is type of Boolean inside the mapStateToProps

Comment: Yes it returns a Boolean (false). @DulangaHeshan

Answer (score 0):

let us see your action creator in full and maybe we can work with that..

Comment: I added my action creator

Comment: in your dispatch action set payload to the variable authenticated and not as an object.. also in your reducer set isAuthenticated in your to action.payload and not action.payload.authenticated

Comment: also in your switch statement set the type to the string "SIGNIN_USER" and not the variable

Comment: I tried this but it stays at false. However my payload still returns true.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way you but exactly i can't say this will work

```
 import { SIGNIN_USER } from "../constants/action-types";

    export default (state = {
        isAuthenticated: false,
    }, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case SIGNIN_USER:
                //console.log('Type: ' + action.type);
                //console.log('Reducer State: ' + state.isAuthenticated);
                //console.log('Reducer Payload: ' + action.payload.authenticated);
               if(action.payload.authenticated){               
                 return {
                    ...state,
                    isAuthenticated
                };
             }
            return {
                    ...state,
                    (!isAuthenticated)
                };
            default:
                return state;
        }
    };
```

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mozilla.dev.developer-tools/XPx2pgz6EQs   also check this

Comment: action.payload.authenticated still returns true but the state isn't set to true according to my component.

Comment: But when I change isAuthenticated to true in state = {} manually it works

Comment: the problen is boolean is not working inside switch case is it?

Comment: i changed above answer try it